# Are contributed plugin translations automatically installed in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, translation

WordPress provides the possibility for users to contribute to translations, e.g. [Jetpack](https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/sl/default/wp-plugins/jetpack).

Are these translations automatically downloaded to WordPress installs, or is it there an approval workflow by the plugin owner first?

Answer (score 1):

The translations hosted in wordpress.org are reviewed and approved by translation validators. Translation validators are recognized with a [badge in the user profile](https://make.wordpress.org/meta/handbook/documentation/profile-badges/). Once approved, the language package is available to be automatically downloaded and installed in any WordPress installation according with its language configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody can export the file, modify it and the plugin developer will never be informed.

It's up to the plugin developer to know that translations are available or that they have been improved on translate.wordpress.org. If he know that, he can eventually provide them in future update.

As far as I know, there is no automatic approval workflow, just a Translation Editor (add translations, manage suggestions, and approve or reject suggested translations) for a language. Always up to him to approve and add your translation to the languages package.